# Prototyping and testing a mobile app with access to camera

Tags: camera

I'm just overwhelmed with the plethora of ways to create prototypes, yet I can't find one to do what I want.

**click on an image, video plays, then open device's camera**

Simple eh? The only way I found to create such a prototype is Form, by [Relativewave](http://relativewave.com) but sadly, it's discontinued, bought out and killed by Google. The current version only works on mac and I don't have a mac at work. I really like the block programming way and node presentation way of doing things with Form, though I'm not much of an expert to have strong preferences.

Any help appreciate,
thanks.

Comment: What kind of device are you talking about here?

Comment: well, I'm prototyping for smartphones and tablets.

Comment: Have you looked at Origami? With Origami you can access the camera of the smartphone in prototypes.

Comment: thanks. awesome. I'm not sure what's the difference between it and Form by Relativewave, looks very similar if not identical. The only thing is "As you review our policy, keep in mind that it applies to all Facebook brands, products and services that do not have a separate privacy policy or that link to this policy, which we call the “Facebook Services” or “Services.”

Comment: that means that anything I create can and will be shared anywhere they please? I'm not sure how that works, does Origami automatically upload and share files? I'll have to think about this, but first I want to understand what's really happening.

Comment: also, for drawings and visual stuff, do I have to start from Sketch, or could I draw stuff in another program? I'm new to all of this and sort of a one man team.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, that they upload your stuff. But you can, if you want. It works with sketch, but you can also just work with screenshots from whatever tool youre using. But I would recommend separating the elements that need to interact in your prototype, for it to work well. You could even design it in Origami, but its not my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

This is quiet a high level of functionality for a prototype.

I assume, as it's not clear in your question, that you are building this prototype to conduct some kind of usability test. I see you could go down one of two paths depending on what kind of usability feedback you need from testing the prototype.

**First method** - Create a functional prototype in Android Studio (depends on your coding skill level), it doesn't have to be pretty it just has to work.

**Second method** - [Wizard of Oz technique](http://www.usabilitynet.org/tools/wizard.htm). Using low fidelity prototypes (paper, card, slideshows...),role play and a sprinkle of imagination you can carry out usability tests as proof of concept.

**Update:** 
I'm not aware of any prototyping tools that can make use of the actual device's camera... Can't you just visualize your idea by animating the flow? If you don't want to make a MVP then this is the best alternative I can see. 
[Here is an example of what I'm talking about.](https://dribbble.com/shots/1439846-FaceScan-app-concept)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to type up an answer. I'm making the prototype to help with an application to a startup accelerator. With a wireframe, what you're talking about, they'll probably gloss over this one very important interaction I'm designing for and be stuck looking at the labels and reading the comments or whatever. they'll miss the point. With Android Studio, I'll be creating an MVP, which is what I'll probably end up doing if I don't get into an accelerator program somewhere.

Comment: thanks, but I'm talking about creating an prototype, not an MVP

Comment: Okay, great to get some more insight. I will update my answer.